# How do I pass a string to React Native function?

Tags: react-native

I have three buttons which should pass a string value to a function that sorts the movies I have in my app based on the word (it starts a query).

```
 const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    getMoviesFiltered();
  },[])

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

  const getMoviesFiltered = async (filter) =>{
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "movies"), orderBy(filter)));
    setMovies(querySnapshot.docs);
  }

  const getMovies = async () =>{
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "movies"), orderBy('name')));
    setMovies(querySnapshot.docs);
  }


  return (
      <View>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('name')}}>
        <Text>Title</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('runtime')}}>
        <Text>Runtime</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('year')}}>
        <Text>Year</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>

 <FlatList
  data = {movies}
  renderItem = {({item}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Modal', item.data())}>
    <Image source={{uri: item.data().pic}}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  />
  </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

I can see that it updates the filter value when I press the button twice (I've read that setState is an asynchronous operation, so I get why that happens), but I'm not sure how to properly pass that string into the getMovies1 function.

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to pass the filter state value to the `getMoviesFiltered` function when it is called. However, you are not passing any arguments to the `getMoviesFiltered` function when you call it in the `TouchableOpacity` `onPress` event handlers.

To fix this, you can pass the filter state value as an argument to the `getMoviesFiltered` function in the `onPress` event handlers like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('name'); 
getMoviesFiltered(filter)}}>
 <Text>Title</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('runtime'); 
getMoviesFiltered(filter)}}>
 <Text>Runtime</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {setFilter('year'); 
getMoviesFiltered(filter)}}>
 <Text>Year</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You may also want to consider moving the `useEffect` hook that calls `getMoviesFiltered` to depend on the filter state value. This will ensure that `getMoviesFiltered` is only called when the filter state value changes. You can do this like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMoviesFiltered(filter);
},[filter])
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting so quickly! The code's working now, but I'm getting this warning:


`[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Function orderBy() called with invalid data. Invalid field path (). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..']`


How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that orderBy is being called with an empty string or an invalid field path.

One way to fix this would be to add a check to make sure that `filter` is not an empty string before calling `orderBy`:


`const getMoviesFiltered = async (filter) =>{
  if (filter) {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db, "movies"), orderBy(filter)));
    setMovies(querySnapshot.docs);
  }
}`